# Write out referenced chapter number

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, numbering

Is it possible to write out the referenced chapter number?

Instead of

`I’m referencing Chapter 1, „Referencing“`

I would like to see

`I’m referencing Chapter one, „Referencing“`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Referencing}
\label{cha:referencing}

I'm referencing Chapter~\ref{cha:referencing},~\enquote{\nameref{cha:referencing}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `cleveref` together with `fmtcount`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{chapter}{\chaptername~#2\numberstringnum{#1}#3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Referenzieren}
\label{cha:referencing}

Dies ist ein Verweis auf \cref{cha:referencing}.

\end{document}
```

Blame Google if the German is bad.

[image]

If you want that also “Kapitel” is in the hyperlink, change the `\crefformat` line into

```
\crefformat{chapter}{#2\chaptername~\numberstringnum{#1}#3}
```

and if you want the number name to begin with a capital letter, use `\Numberstringnum`.

Comment: Google is right in this case. But as a German I would say that the verbal expression of the number should be uppercase, i.e. `Eins`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the help on language. I added the necessary change to make.

Comment: No problem. I think the style of `eins` or `Eins` depends on the context anyway, your solution was correct in the sense of German language anyway.

Comment: If I use this (for English, not German), I get "CHAPTER three" rather than "Chapter three".

Comment: @retorquere Please, open a new question, with a reference to this one, with a minimal example.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is possible, but it's necessary to extract the chapter number first before it can be used. `\ref...` does not provide a number at all, so `refcount` and its `getrefnumber` comes into action. This will produce `1` here.

To get a verbal expression of `1` as `Eins` here, use `\Numberstringnum` or `\numberstringnum` for `eins` from `fmtcount` package.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hallo Welt}
I'm referencing Chapter~\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{cha:referencing}},~\enquote{\nameref{cha:referencing}}

\chapter{Referencing}
\label{cha:referencing}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The mixing of languages is a little bit weird ;-)

Comment: You could even use `cleveref`'s command `\Cref{...}` to get `Chapter` automatically

Comment: Thank you very much! I accept @egreg's answer because I like the cref style, however you've been very helpful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little macro to deal with german cardinals **and** ordinals in a proper way. For the latter, `\Ordinalstringnum` and `\ordinalstringnum` from `fmtcount` can't be used effectively, as they only give the strong form (e.g. "erster", which is quite useless if you want to print "erstes Kapitel", "das erste Kapitel" etc.). Here's the code with some example output:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{refcount,fmtcount}

\newcommand{\refzw}[2][o]{%
\def\refnum{\getrefnumber{#2}}%
\lowercase{\ifnum\ifx#1}o\ifnum\refnum=1 1\else\ifnum\refnum=3 1\else\ifnum\refnum=7 1\else\ifnum\refnum=8 1\else0\fi\fi\fi\fi\else0\fi=1%
\ifnum\refnum=1\def\zw{ers}\def\zwg{Ers}\fi%
\ifnum\refnum=3\def\zw{drit}\def\zwg{Drit}\fi%
\ifnum\refnum=7\def\zw{sieb}\def\zwg{Sieb}\fi%
\ifnum\refnum=8\def\zw{ach}\def\zwg{Ach}\fi%
\else\def\zwg{\Numberstringnum{\refnum}}\def\zw{\numberstringnum{\refnum}}    \fi%
\if1\ifx#1O1\else\ifx#1K1\else0\fi\fi\zwg\else\zw\fi%
\ifnum\refnum>19\lowercase{\ifx#1o{s}\fi}\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Einleitung}\label{einl}
\refzw[O]{einl}tens steht das \refzw{einl}te Kapitel in Kapitel \refzw[k]{einl} – oder schreibt man Kapitel \refzw[K]{einl}? Dann gibts aber noch ein \refzw{haupt1}tes und ein \refzw{haupt2}tes Kapitel, aber kein dreites. Dann kommen die Kapitel \refzw[K]{haupt3} und \refzw[K]{haupt4}.
\section{Hauptteil}\label{haupt1}
\section{Fazit}\label{haupt2}
\section{Schluss}\label{haupt3}
\section{jetzt}\label{haupt4}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The command takes the reference key as a mandatory and one of the following options as an optional argument:

- o (default) prints ordinal number, e.g. "ers"
- O prints capitalized ordinal number, e.g. "Ers"
- k prints cardinal number, e.g. "eins"
- K prints capitalized cardinal number, e.g. "Eins"

As you may have noticed, the ordinal numbers are printed without any endings, you have to write e.g. "im \refzw{key}ten Kapitel" for it to output "im ersten Kapitel". The macro works with \section headlines in articles as well as \chapter in books and prints correct numbers until 100. It needs the following packages:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{fmtcount}
\usepackage{refcount}
```

or

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{refcount,fmtcount}
```

`fmtcount` by the way may need to be updated, an older version (which came with Ubuntu 14.04's TexLive) wrongly printed "ein**s**undzwanzig".

### Print out long version

If you want it to print out "erste" instead of "ers" (so just to add "n", "s" etc.), replace the `}` at the end by:

```
\lowercase{\ifx#1}ote\fi%
}
```

Comment: Btw, correct german would be "Kapitel eins", *not* capitalizing the numeral (see [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eins_Zahl) and [canoonet](http://www.canoo.net/spelling/eins:A:Card)). I apologize for doing it wrong in the above example!

Comment: you can always edit your post…

Comment: I perceive this as a matter of style and therefore the duden directions not binding in this case. Besides, it would destroy my neat example. ;)