# get the litteral number of a section reference

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, fmtcount

I try to put the literal number of section instead of the digital number (“ten” instead of ”10”) when I get his number by `\ref{}` command.

So, to transform a digital number into a literal number I use the `\numberstringnum{}` command from the `fmtcount` package, like in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\label{sec:foo}

lorem ipsum dolor

\section{bar}
foo reference number : \ref{sec:foo}

foo reference litteral : \numberstringnum{\ref{sec:foo}} % See here

\end{document}
```

But, `xelatex` or `pdflatex` refuse to compile it:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.14 ...litteral : \numberstringnum{\ref{sec:foo}}
```

So, how can I transform the number reference into textual literal number?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Write out referenced chapter number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254356/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `refcount` and `\getrefnumber`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount,refcount}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\label{sec:foo}

lorem ipsum dolor

\section{bar}
foo reference number: \ref{sec:foo}

foo reference in words: \numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{sec:foo}} % See here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This approach doesn't work because the internals of `\ref` also checks if the label is defined, and this is not a valid number to be given to `\numberstringnum`.

One approach is to steal the definition of `\ref` from the LaTeX kernel and adapt it to work with `\numberstringnum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\makeatletter
\def\@setnumref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \numberstringnum{\expandafter#2#1}\null
  \fi}
\def\numref#1{\expandafter\@setnumref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoftwo{#1}}
\def\numpageref#1{\expandafter\@setnumref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@secondoftwo{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\label{sec:foo}

lorem ipsum dolor

\section{bar}
foo reference number : \ref{sec:foo}

foo reference litteral : \numref{sec:foo} on page \numpageref{sec:foo} % See here

\end{document}
```

> [image]